# Git - Duplicate commit issue

Tags: git

I accidentally created commits by "unknown" in my repository, and decided to try running a command from [here](http://coffee.geek.nz/how-change-author-git.html):

```
git filter-branch --commit-filter '
        if [ "$GIT_COMMITTER_NAME" = "unknown" ];
        then
                GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="..";
                GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="..";
                GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="...";
                GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="...";
                git commit-tree "$@";
        else
                git commit-tree "$@";
        fi' HEAD
```

At first I thought everything was fine, until I noticed in gitk that every commit prior to running this was duplicated, not simply edited as I originally thought.

Is it possible to clean this up?

**EDIT:** OK, gitk is showing both the old commits (the ones with the "unknown" commiters mixed in) and the new commits (the rewritten ones), split up at a certain point around halfway. Think a bunch of commits, then duplicated (and with the edits), and stacked on top of the original ones. What I want to do is if possible, is remove the original ones.

Comment: Let's see if I'm getting this: do you have a commit tree that looks like `...--a--b--c--(*)--a'--b'--c'--d--e`, where `(*)` is the commit on which you ran the bad command, `[abc]'` are erroneously duplicated commits you want to delete, and `[de]` are commits you want to keep?

Comment: Well, it's more complicated due to branching, but basically as you said, but I want to keep the `'` ones as they have the author fields fixed.

Comment: Okay, so you want to delete [abc], but keep [abc]'?

Comment: Yes, I want to delete my original commits.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer was the files in `.git/refs/original`, and how the command I found should not have ended in `HEAD` but instead with `--tag-name-filter cat -- --all`.

Cheers to _Vi and wereHamster from the `#git` channel for the help.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the last good commit, save your bacon with this:

```
git reset <last_good_commit>   # Warp back to a good state.
git push -f master             # Push the changes up (you need -f to force it to
                               #  obliterate old commits).
```

If you want to tread more carefully (for example, if there are good and bad commits mixed in after `<last_good_commit>`), use `git rebase -i` to cherry-pick the good ones that should stay behind.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with the command line, and I'm not sure what cherry picking or rebasing are... also, I've added a clarification on what I want to do.