# How to revert a 'git filter-branch -f --env-filter'

Tags: git, commit, revert, git-filter-branch

I am quite a newb regarding git and usually git commit, pull and push are the only commands I do.
Recently noticed that my commits were set to a default name and email and wanted to change it.
Stupidly I ran this which I found in a post somewhere:

```
git filter-branch -f --env-filter "GIT_AUTHOR_NAME='Newname'; GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL='newemail'; 
GIT_COMMITER_NAME='Newname'; GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL='newemail';" HEAD
```

I thought this would change only my commits, but instead it changed all commits in the repo to have my name and email. Of course to continue my "dumbness" I pushed the changes.

Also I seem to have lost history and all commits on github seem to have a duplicate entry as well. One with my name and email and the original one.

Is there a way to revert this? Maybe using a copy of a previous pull to push the original info?

Comment: Did you check this one out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1983101/git-duplicate-commit-issue it seems to be a duplicate

Comment: It's more or less the same yes, although I wanted to revert the info on those commits as well and not only get rid of duplicates. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A colleague was able to speak with some git pros and it seems that a 'git push -f' from a previous copy solved the issue. Also, I needed to do a git pull --rebase on my copy.

Thanks for your help guys.

Answer (score 8):

If you haven't done anything to clean up loose objects after you did the filter-branch command, you can reset your master branch (assuming HEAD was master when you gave the command):

```
git reset --hard refs/original/master
```

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't cleanup yet you can reset your branch with : `git reset --hard refs/original/master` this will reload all the original files prior to your attempt then do:

`git filter-branch -f --env-filter "GIT_AUTHOR_NAME='Newname'; GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL='newemail'; GIT_COMMITER_NAME='Newname'; GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL='newemail';" "--tag-name-filter cat -- --all"`